# <router-view> not funcitoning on upgrade to vue.js 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am completely stuck on getting a component to render through router-view using the vue.js 2.0 and vue-router.

I have vue devtools installed and I do see the "fragment" label next to  router-view, but no other details.

Might be important to note that I am using laravel-elixir-vueify and browserify.

App.js

```
var Vue = require('Vue');
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');

import dashboard from './components/dashboard.vue'

Vue.component('dashboard', dashboard);

Vue.use(VueRouter);


const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: dashboard }
  ]

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#vueapp')
```

dashboard.blade.php

```
<div id="vueapp">
  //other code removed for space
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

dashboard.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="block">
          <div id="showCalendar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
//Note: I tried adding an extra <div></div> within the template, but that didn't make a difference. 

<script>

export default{

mounted: function() {

    this.CompCalendar();
},
methods: {

    CompCalendar: function() {

                /* Initialize FullCalendar */
                var date = new Date();
                var d = date.getDate();
                var m = date.getMonth();
                var y = date.getFullYear();

        this.$nextTick(function() {
            var events = this.$http.get('/events/local/index')
                .then(function(response){

                    $('#showCalendar').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        //unimportant options
                    },
                    //unimportant options
                    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){

                        var eventId = calEvent.id;
                        router.push({
                            path: 'details/'+eventId

                        });
                    },
                    });
                })
        });
    }
   }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this is related to a laravel-elixir-vueify conflict that is referencing vue 1.0

Comment: did you run a gulp after updating? what does your packages.json and gulpfile.js look like?

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing, you dont need to register `Vue.component('dashboard', dashboard)` 
The Reference to in the routes is enough.
Everything else looks good for me. Do you have any Errors in your console?

Try `routes = [ { path: '', component ..`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't registered any component for this action

```
router.push({
   path: 'details/'+eventId
});
```

It seems like you need something like that in your router:

```
 { path: '/details', component: Details }
```